# Apache Karaf startup script. How to set more perm memory?

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory, permgen, apache-karaf

I am trying to figure out how to increase karaf's permgen memory. In the karaf's start up script I see that there is:

```
if not "%JAVA_PERM_MEM%" == "" (
    set DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS=%DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS% -XX:PermSize=%JAVA_PERM_MEM%
)
if not "%JAVA_MAX_PERM_MEM%" == "" (
    set DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS=%DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS% -XX:MaxPermSize=%JAVA_MAX_PERM_MEM%
)
```

I understand that the `JAVA_PERM_MEM` and `JAVA_MAX_PERM_MEM` is the variables but they are not defined anywhere in startup script except here.

The karaf is running on live machine so I do not want to make any experiments on it I need to be sure if doing like this:

```
if not "%JAVA_PERM_MEM%" == "" (
    set DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS=%DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS% -XX:PermSize=512M
)
if not "%JAVA_MAX_PERM_MEM%" == "" (
    set DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS=%DEFAULT_JAVA_OPTS% -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
)
```

will increase the permgen memory? The reason I need to do it is because I keep getting the: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`

**EDIT:**

All the bundles deployed on karaf are spring related, they have camel routes, cxf endpoints, OpenJPA persistence configuration all is manage via Spring. But I do not think that there is the problem, because as I know OutOfMemory PermGen space means there is not enough memory for all deployed applications. If someone know where might be the issue it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These variables are probably going to be read from your environment, so just define them.

```
export JAVA_PERM_MEM...
```

About the PermGen exception, do you may be use spring DM? or some spring related osgi bundles? There are a couple of issues around that.

Comment: I have edited my question, there are spring related bundles deployed into karaf.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis you could try to increase this memory, but usually it is not enough. You could tell Java to GC this memory also. There are answers like this here on SO

Comment: You don't need to precify this variable manually, just edit %container%/bin/setenv script